# AngularJS : Directive shell that allows user defined content with directive scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-transclude

Here's a plunker example you can see: http://plnkr.co/edit/NQT8oUv9iunz2hD2pf8H

I have a directive that I would like to turn into a web component. I've thought of several ways as to how I can achieve that with AngularJS but am having difficulty with a piece of it. I'm hoping someone can explain my misstep rather than tell me a different way to do it.

Imagine you have a directive component that sets up some shell with css classes maybe some sub components, etc.. but lets the user define the main content of the component. Something like the following:

```
<my-list items="ctrl.stuff">
    <div>List Item: {{ item.name }}</div>
</my-list>
```

The HTML for the list directive could be something like the following (with OOCSS):

```
<ul class="mas pam bas border--color-2">
    <li ng-repeat="items in item track by item.id" ng-transclude></li>
</ul>
```

Normally this can be solved in the link function by linking the directives scope to the new content. And it does work for other components. However introducing the ng-repeat seems to break that portion of the control. From what I can tell, the appropriate place might be the compile function but the documentation says the transcludeFn parameter will be deprecated so I'm not sure how to proceed.

I should also note that when using the beta AngularJS, there is either a bug or a new paradigm coming, because this is no longer a problem. It seems like the transcluded content always gets access to the directives scope as well as the outer controllers scope.

I really appreciate any enlightenment on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's by design that content added via `ng-transclude` will bind with an outer controller scope, not a scope of the current element that `ng-transclude` is on.

You could solve the problem by copy the [ng-transclude's code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/ng/directive/ngTransclude.js#L67) and modify it a bit to give a correct scope:

```
.directive('myTransclude', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers, transcludeFn) {
      transcludeFn(scope, function(nodes) {
        element.empty();
        element.append(nodes);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And replace the `ng-transclude` with `my-transclude` in your directive template.

**Example Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/i7ohGeRiO3m5kfxOehC1?p=preview

Comment: Interesting, so I can't use the built-in ng-transclude for what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks!